# collapsed row shows while space in RadGridView silverlight

Tags: silverlight, telerik, silverlight-5.0, telerik-grid

I am using one `RadGridView` in my program.
I have 3 tables to show in 3 Rows, but in some case (condition base) I need to show only 3rd row's table.

In this scenario I have changed visibility of 1st and 2nd row to collapsed, but this method shows some bank space on the top of 3rd row table.

I tried to achieve this by ...

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

and

```
<RowDefinition  Height="*" />
```

but in both cases it shows white space.

Comment: Can you show an example of the xaml you have for the grids?